# Pipe Delimited List with numbers into array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex

In the database I'm working on there's a string like this

```
1-Test Response|9-DNC|
```

This can have up to 9 pipe delimited items.

What I'm looking  for advice on is the best possible way to take this string and turn it into an array with the number as the key and the string as the value.

I really suck with Regex. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you're doing this in your database, then your database structure is wrong.

Comment: You may use: `/(\d+)-([^|]+)/` in `preg_match_all` and then use `array_combine`

Comment: It looks cleaner with `regex` but you don't need `regex` to parse the string. Two calls to [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) can do miracles.

Comment: @AlexKarshin This is how the Vicidial Database is structured. I don't really have a choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I went about it for anyone else wondering

```
$SurveyOptions = preg_match_all('/(\d+)-([^|]+)/', 
$res['survey_response_digit_map'], $matches);
$finalArray = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not your fault you have the DB structured this way, please accept my sincere condolences. It must be hell working with this. Meh.

Now, to the point. You do not need regex to work with this string. If you have a problem and you want to solve it with regex, you have two problems.

Instead, use `explode()`.

```
$testString = "1-Test Response|9-DNC|";
$result = [];
$explodedByPipeString = explode("|", $testString);

foreach($explodedByPipeString as $k => $v)
{
    $explodedByDashString = explode("-", $v);

    if(is_numeric($explodedByDashString[0]))
    {
        $result[$explodedByDashString[0]] = $explodedByDashString[1];
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

This gives

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(13) "Test Response"
  [9]=>
  string(3) "DNC"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the delimters: `-` and `|` do not exist in the keys or values, here is another non-regex way to tackle the string:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/80jd9))

```
$string = '1-Test Response|9-DNC|';
$string = str_replace(['-', '|'], ['=', '&'], $string);  // generates: 1=Test Response&9=DNC&
parse_str($string, $result);
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 'Test Response',
  9 => 'DNC',
)
```